# Modifying a form object created by application.run(form1)

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and trying to figure out how to edit a form from another class. The form is created by the default VS approach, as so:

```
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

I've created a method in the Form1.cs file, just as a test for how to update a label1 field that is in Form1. Here is the method:

```
public void UpdateLabel(string state = "Changed Text")
{
  label1.Text = state;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the Application.Run command doesn't provide for a named object of type Form1. So when I want to trigger the UpdateLabel method from Program.cs, like so:

```
XXX.UpdateLabel();
```

I don't have an object to target to access the form. If I were creating the form manually, then I believe this would work fine:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
myForm.UpdateLabel();
```

With the Application.Run(Form1) that the Windows Form Application provides, how do I access the form object that is being created? Also, is this the approach I should be taking for this type of problem, or is there a better method?

Comment: what other class are you trying to access the Form1 instance from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could integrate your last example in this way....

```
static void Main() 
{ 
  Application.EnableVisualStyles(); 
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
  Form1 myForm = new Form1();
  myForm.UpdateLabel();
  Application.Run(myForm); 
}
```

but let me ask you: Why your logic dictates to do this outside the Form1 constructor?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    label1.Text = "Changed Text";
}
```

EDIT: Following the comments below I think you should work on something like this:

```
MyApplicationCode appCode;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    appCode = new MyApplicationCode();

    this.Text = appCode.GetFormText();
    label1.Text = appCode.GetLabelText();
    cmdSave.Enabled = appCode.UserHasSavePermission();
    ...... // and so on for other decisions on 

}
```

Comment: Currently I have a version of a program I've written where I just wrote all of the functional code within the form1.cs file. I'd like to separate out the parts of the code that don't use the form so that those are easier to maintain and build upon.

I'm seeing a few ways to do this:
    1. Take the approach in my initial post, which is to control form1 from the other class (fBook).
    2. Have form1 create a copy of fBook and call its methods, which will return the values to update form1 with.
    3. Have program.cs create objects of each class and then direct things somehow from there.
Ideas?

Comment: @Ben Your second approach would be the best option.  You don't want to put this type of code in your `Main` method.

Comment: I'd agree with servy. In particular if you are taking code out of the form that doesn't need the form then it shouldn't need a reference to the form. In general if the form is doing stuff with other data (eg processing input to create an output) then that is best done from the form itself, calling a separate library, class or whatever as appropriate.

Comment: @Servy, absolutely right, Form1 should change its contents/appearance calling methods on a class that knows the conditions, configurations or whatelse that leads to the Form1 changes. Everything stuffed there and Form1 asks to an instance of this class how to reconfigure itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could fix the immediate issue with:

```
Form1 form = new Form1());

form.UpdateLabel();

Application.Run(form);
```

As for the second question, it really depends on what you are trying to ultimately achieve.

Answer (score 1):

So you have some fairly complicated logic that is used to determine the initial value of some controls in your form.  Due to the complexity of that logic, you would prefer to extract that code from the definition of `Form1` and move it to another class.  That is all good so far.

You can create some other class, have `Form1` *use* that class, and have it provide a value to `Form1`.  Rather than having some other class that has-a `Form1` (which would be the effect of putting your code in `Main`, `Form1` should have that other class.

Implementing this is fairly simple.  You create another class, you give it an instance or static method that returns a string.  `Form1` either calls the static method, or creates an instance of the class and calls the instance method.  It then sets a label based on the results of that method.

Answer (score 0):

Application.Run is typically used to launch a WinForms application until such a point that that application closes. What function of your Program.cs class is supposed to call UpdateLabel? Is your application launched externally with label value parameters?