# Modifying main form and its controls in application.Run C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to modify text on button(for example) in main form of my application.
But this thing does not work for the window which was created before `Application.Run()`.

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 Mainwindow = new Form1();
        Application.Run(Mainwindow);
        ///Some stuff to do...
        Mainwindow.button1.Text = "TextToChangeTo"; // And nothing happens here
    }
```

Is there any nice workaround to be applied here?

Comment: This should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897506/modifying-a-form-object-created-by-application-runform1

Comment: May I ask why don't you change it directly in designer,or on the form load?

Comment: Because i need to change controls state after executing multiple things like delegates and would like to keep all working process away from form constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the button text in the main form after the `Application.Run()` method. This is not correct as the text wont be set until after the application has finished.

Try adding the code to the constructor of the MainWindow() or in the load event. Example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.button1.Text = "Some Text";
    }
}
```

**Update**

Display two possible solutions for manipulating controls on another form.

Passing the `MainWindow` to another form.

*Form2*

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(MainWindow mainWndow)
        :this()
    {
        this.mainWindow = mainWndow;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        if (this.mainWindow != null)
            this.mainWindow.button1.Text = "I set your text";
    }
}
```

*MainWindow*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2(this);
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

This example passes the instance of `MainWindow` by using the `this` keyword. In `Form2` you will see the `DoWork()` then can set the value.

Creating a static reference to MainWindow in your Program class.

*Program.cs*

```
static class Program
{
    public static MainWindow MainWindow { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Program.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        Application.Run(Program.MainWindow);
    }
}
```

*Form2.cs*

```
public void DoWork()
{
    Program.MainWindow.button1.Text = "I set your text";
}
```

Comment: Editing inside form is working nicely, but i trying to modify controls from outside of the form, which does not works out only when it is from App.Run();

Comment: You can modify the controls you just need a reference to the form. This can be done  many ways such as passing the form object to another window. Creating a static reference to the form. I will add an example of both.

Answer (score 0):

If you add something after `Application.Run(MainWindow)` it executes after `MainWindow` close.
So add before it.

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Form1 Mainwindow = new Form1();

    Mainwindow.button1.Text = "TextToChangeTo"; 

    Application.Run(Mainwindow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should edit your code like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.button1.Text = "Some Text";
        Application.Run(frm);
    }
```